# What is the regex expression to extract 3 letter word starting with M followed by 2 number?

Tags: regex

I want to extract first 3 letters of the sentence which start with M and are followed by 2 digits.

If sentence is M30 INTHE SKY then output should be M30. IF sentence is THE INTHE SKY then answer should be np.nan(i.e. false as it didnot start with M)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`M\d{2}`

- `M` for literal M
- `\d` to match one digit
- `{x}` to match the previous token x times

If you do a search it will return the matched result; gives empty otherwise.